# In PHP, how do you access the dom and print out its nodeValue or value in general using the querySelector method?

Tags: php, dom, jquery-selectors

```
<input id="button01" type="button" value="add" onclick="add()">7</input>
<input id ="button02" type="button" value="sub" onclick="sub()">8</input>
<input id="button03" type="button" value="div" onclick="div()">9</input>
<input id="button04" type="button" value="0" name="button04">10</input>
<?php

$document->querySelector('#button04')->nodeValue;
?>
```

I would like to use querySelector, I honestly do not want an answer pertaining to Ajax, I would simply like to echo the nodeValue and value of button04. Thank you.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. It runs _before_ any output is given to the browser. So PHP will never be able to select values from the DOM after and display them. Ajax is your only option if you don't want the website to refresh. If you do, you have to submit the values as a form and save them in variables or sessions / cookies to retrieve them from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to access the value of your button

```
$('#button04').val();
```

To access the node value you can use the following:

```
$('#button04').text();
```

Comment: ultimately I am trying to assign that value to a php variable so i can move it across pages. this is possible rihgt?

Comment: does ---$document->querySelector('#button04')->nodeValue;--- not register any advice for this situation?